# Macro: Insert data into another empty sheet, won't insert

Tags: vba, excel

I want to inset data into a new empty sheet,but when I define the loop to read the new sheet,it won't do the insertion.

> I do the first **For** to define the empty sheet and the second **For** to read the data of the sheet that contains the data.
>   Then I do the logic.But i won't do the importation.
>   Whats wrong? Do I need to reset the empty sheet or something?

`

`For i= 2 To last_row(ws_EmptySheet)`

```
   For j = 2 To last_row(ws_Data)

       Set Range_Data = ws_Data.Range("A" & j, "N" & Rows.Count)
```

`If ws_Data.Range("D" & j) = 3 Then`

`supplier = ws_Data.Range("A" & j)
    ind = j
    indF = j + 1`

```
For Each supplier In ws_Data


state = ws_Data.Range("K" & ind, "N" & Rows.Count).Find(What:="State", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Offset(0, 3)
  If (state<> "") Then
       r = ws_Data.Range("K" & ind, "N" & Rows.Count).Find(What:="Nazione", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Row
```

`'IndI = r`

```
    Set rngEmpty = ws_EmptySheet.Range("A" & i)

    i2 = i
```

`i = i + 1`

`indF = indF + 1`

`On Error Resume Next`

```
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
```

`rngEmpty = ""`

```
 Else
```

`supplier = ws_Data.Range("A" & r)`

`supplierEmpty = ws_EmptySheet.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="STATE", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
        rngEmpty.Offset(0, supplierEmpty - 1) = supplier`

`city = ws_Data.Range("B" & r, "N" & indF)`

`cityEmpty = ws_AltreSedi.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="CITY", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
          rngEmpty.Offset(0, cityEmpty - 1) = city`

`End If`

```
     End If

      Next

       End If
     j = j + 1
  Next
```

`

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0):

Why do you do **for** to define empty sheet. If you create a new empty sheet, I recoment just to write its number or name.

Comment: If I dont use a for ,it will overwrite the data selected only in the i=2 row..Even if I increment the index.How can I transfer the data after?